# Need a way to find $a,b$ for the vector $x' = ax + by$ such that for a matrix $A$ of size $ m \times n$, $Ax'$ is orthogonal to $Ay$

Tags: matrices, vectors, algorithms, matrix-norms

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ such that $$1 \leq m \leq \frac12 n < n \leq 100$$ denote the known numbers of rows and columns of an unknown matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$. Though one does **not** have access to the matrix $A$, for any given vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ one can get $\| Ax \|_2$ by sending $x$ to a server that knows $A$. Given two vectors $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, find a unit vector $x' = ax + by$ for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $Ax' \perp Ay$. One guarantee we have is that $\|A \|_2 \leq \frac32$.

---

I am working on this problem and struggling to find a way to deduce a formula for $a, b$ such that $x'$ satisfies the constraints.

Comment: Hey! I don't compute $ ||Ax||_2 $ myself. There is a server that knows $A$ but it is hidden from me. I can send $x$ to this server and it will return  $ ||Ax||_2 $.

Answer (score 1):

Since for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, you have an the knowledge of $\| Ax \|$, you also have the knowledge of $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle$ for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (due to the polarization identity).

With this, the problem is to find $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the following equations hold:

$$a^2 \| x \|^2 + 2ab \langle x, y \rangle + b^2 \| y \|^2 = 1.$$

$$a \langle Ax, Ay \rangle + b \| Ay \|^2 = 0.$$

Considering that the only unknowns in these equations are $a, b$, this could be solvable. The simplest case is when $y \in \ker A$, for which the problem is under-determined, and particularly, any unit vector (any values of $a, b$ that make $x'$ into a unit vector) works!

For the non-trivial case of $y \notin \ker A$, we have from the second equation $b = - a \frac{\langle Ax, Ay \rangle}{\| Ay \|^2}$, and hence

$$a^2 \| x \|^2 - 2a^2 \frac{\langle Ax, Ay \rangle \langle x, y \rangle}{\| Ay \|^2} + a^2 \frac{\langle Ax, Ay \rangle^2}{\| Ay \|^4} = 1.$$

This gives you your solution!

---

**Polarization Identity:** Let $V$ be a real vector space with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Then, for every $x \in V$, we have

$$\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \left( \| x + y \|^2 - \| x - y \|^2 \right),$$

where $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm on $V$ induced by the inner product.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick and detailed answer. However, i don't have access to $Ax$ nor $Ay$. I can ask the server to send me the $\mathcal{l}_2$ norm of $Ax$ but not the $Ax$ itself. So i don't know how i would calculate $b$ in your answer.

Comment: Can you use the polarization identity I have mentioned in the edit to get the inner product?

Comment: I could come to this conclusion: 
$$ < Ax, Ay> = \frac{1}{4} (|| Ax + Ay||^2 - ||Ax - Ay||^2) = \frac{1}{2} (||Ax||^2 + ||Ay||^2 - ||Ax - Ay||^2 ) $$. But i don't see how to calculate second part of this equation now.

Comment: @CGI-Hood: Your conclusion is incorrect! How could you split $\|  Ax + Ay \|^2$ into $\| Ax \|^2 + \| Ay \|^2$? My point was that you know $x, y$ and hence your server knows $Ax$ and $Ay$. Therefore, it also knows $A (x + y) = Ax + Ay$ and $A (x - y) = Ax - Ay$. The norms of these vectors can be calculated in whichever server you are using. The theoretical formula to reconstruct the inner product from the norm is the polarization identity, in which you know everything from the right hand side. Use it, and plug it into the equations I gave in my answer, you will find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hello again! The important point here is that the server will only provide $||Ax||_2$. Whatever it knows is not relevant since we won't be able to access it. Also my conclusion comes from wikipedia.

Comment: You have written in your question "for any given vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, one can get $\| Ax \|$". A few lines later you write "given $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$", you want to find something. Since $x$ and $y$ are initially given to you, you must know these vectors. Therefore, you know $x + y$ and $x - y$. Put them into your server to get $\| A (x + y ) \|$ and $\| A (x - y ) \|$. Now do you understand it?

Comment: Hey! Thanks again for the help, i am going to try your approach again see if it works. I'll let you take a look at this website: https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/linearmethods/innerproductspaces#:~:text=Parallelogram%20law%3A%20If%20X%20is,4%E2%9F%A8x%2Cy%E2%9F%A9.
From my point of view, since $Ax' \perp Ay$ that means their dot product is 0,  $(Ax')^T Ay = 0$ which is why we can say $||Ax' + Ay || ^2 = ||Ax'||^2 + ||Ay||^2$ according to Pythagoras' theorem.